# Spark DF Behavior without Caching

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I cant find a clear (to a newbie like me) answer to this online.

If I create a spark df (using pyspark if that matters, I dont think it does) like:

```
new_df = spark.sql ("select * from old_df)
print(new_df.count())
```

**1) Does new_df exist now due to the count() command?**

**2) If I instead did new_df.show(5) instead of count() does this change the answer to #1?**

If I then do this

```
new_df =new_df.withColumn('foo', new column formula)
print(new_df.count())
```

**3) Does the initial step to create new_dt get re-ran before the new column is created?**

**4) Would new_DF.cache() change the responses?**

**I am confused about WHEN something actually runs and if steps get reran as more and more is done or changed with a DF.**

EDIT:

What I meant for number 4 was if the sequence of commands had been:

```
 new_df = spark.sql ("select * from old_df)
 print(new_df.count())
 **new_df.cache()**
 new_df =new_df.withColumn('foo', new column formula)
 print(new_df.count())
```

versus the same without **new_df.cache()** would this keep the second
 print(new_df.count()) from triggering a rebuild of new_df from old_df assuming old_df was not cached.

Answer (score 1):

Spark has [**Actions**](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/rdd-programming-guide.html#actions) and [**Transformations**](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/rdd-programming-guide.html#transformations)

#### Actions

Actions, like `df.count()` actually do work and can return a new dataframe.

#### Transformations

Transformations, like `spark.sql("select * from old_df")`,  don't create new dataframes. These create a DAG which is like a recipe for a new dataframe.

#### Your Questions, Summarized

1) Does new_df exist now due to the count() command?
**yes**

2) If I instead did new_df.show(5) instead of count() does this change the answer to #1?
**nope, they're both actions**

3) Does the initial step to create new_dt get re-ran before the new column is created?
**probably, but this is up to Spark's optimizer**

4) Would new_DF.cache() change the responses?
**no, `cache()` is a lazy operation**

I am confused about WHEN something actually runs and if steps get reran as more and more is done or changed with a DF.

If you want to learn more I'd recommend trying one of databricks notebooks like the one here https://docs.databricks.com/_static/notebooks/cs100x-2015-introduction-to-big-data/module-2--spark-tutorial-lab.html
Their latest book *Spark: The Definitive Guide* is also top-notch

Comment: One confusion on how count() and show() may differ. It seems I have observed when a dataframe is massive (my example is a billion rows), if I add a column to it using withColumn() and then call show(5) on that dataframe, it runs quick. It runs a really long time if instead of show() I used count(). I assumed this was because show(5) only triggered creation of 5 rows. Is that right or was I confused?

Comment: Yup, you've got the hang of this :)

Comment: So show(n) does only trigger the calculation of n rows?

Comment: I can't guarantee that for all cases, but here that is true

Answer (score 1):

The best place to get answers to these questions is the documentation on RDDs, transformations, and actions. This is [here in the Spark documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/rdd-programming-guide.html#rdd-operations).

To give short answers to your questions:

1. *Does new_df exist now due to the count() command?*

   The data frame exists when it is defined (`new_df = spark.sql ("select * from old_df)`). However, due to the lazy evaluation of Spark, computation is delayed until `new_df.count()` executes.
2. *If I instead did new_df.show(5) instead of count() does this change the answer to #1?*

   No
3. *Does the initial step to create new_dt get re-ran before the new column is created?*

   This depends on the parents of `new_df`. If `old_df` was cached, then the steps won't be rerun because the results would have been already computed and made available for subsequent uses.
4. *Would new_DF.cache() change the responses?*

   `cache()` causes the results/data to be cached on execution of the first action. As long as the data is still in memory (before `unpersist` is called), *subsequent* actions on the data frame or its descendents will not cause the computation of `new_df` to be done.

   So the answer is NO because you're calling only one action once on `new_df`.

Comment: Regarding #4, I meant if I was to have issued cache() prior to the withColumn() step, would the data frame not have been rebuilt (assuming that its parents were not cached). I take it that this answer is 'yes it would make a difference'.

Comment: @B_Miner If you'd build `new_df` with `new_df = new_df.cache().withColumn('foo', new column formula)`, then the first time `new_df.count()` runs after this would cause the old `new_df` to be cached. The difference only matters when actions are executed after this. Remember, data frames and their backing RDDs are immutable, so `new_df = new_df.cache().withColumn()` makes 2 new data frames, of which one is cached (with no reference/variable kept for it), but recorded in the lineage of the latest `new_df` (the one with an additional column)

Comment: Edited the question to hopefully make #4 more clear.